# Creating instances within the if statement of a loop and using them

Tags: rust, ownership

I am trying to parse a string of multiple lines that contain information about points and polygons.

The issue I am facing is with ownership in Rust. In languages like C# or C++, I can declare a variable and then instantiate it at a certain point, then use that variable later on. But in Rust, this causes an ownership problem.

How can I handle this situation in Rust?

```
fn main() {
    // Point struct
    struct Point {
        x: f64,
        y: f64,
    }

    // Polygon struct that has points
    struct Polygon {
        points: Vec<Point>,
    }

    // Implement the Polygon struct
    impl Polygon {
        fn new() -> Self {
            Self { points: Vec::new() }
        }
    }

    // Surface struct that has polygons
    struct Surface {
        polygons: Vec<Polygon>,
    }

    // Implement the Surface struct
    impl Surface {
        fn new() -> Self {
            Self { polygons: Vec::new() }
        }
    }

    // string polygons
    let strs = "
    SB
        PB
            PT 350 130
            PT 350 170
            PT 450 170
        PE 
        PB
            PT 370 150
            PT 370 160
            PT 430 160
        PE
    SE";

    let mut surface = Surface::new();
    let mut poly:Polygon = Polygon::new();

    let lines: Vec<&str> = strs.lines().collect();
    for line in lines.iter().map(|s| s.trim()) {
        
        if line == "SB" {
            surface = Surface::new();
        } else if line == "PB" {
            poly = Polygon::new();
            surface.polygons.push(poly);
        } else if line.starts_with("PT") {
            let mut parts = line.split_whitespace();
            parts.next(); // skip "PT"
            let x: f64 = parts.next().unwrap().parse().unwrap();
            let y: f64 = parts.next().unwrap().parse().unwrap();
            let pt = Point { x, y };

            poly.points.push(pt); // <-- Error
            // surface.polygons.last_mut().unwrap().points.push(pt); // <-- OK
        }
    }

    // Print the Surface polygons points
    for poly in surface.polygons.iter() {
        println!("PB");
        for point in poly.points.iter() {
            println!("\tx: {}, y: {}", point.x, point.y);
        }
        println!("PE");
    }
}
```

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `poly`
  --> src/main.rs:65:13
   |
48 |     let mut poly:Polygon = Polygon::new();
   |         -------- move occurs because `poly` has type `Polygon`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
57 |             surface.polygons.push(poly);
   |                                   ---- value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
...
65 |             poly.points.push(pt); // <-- Error
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

Comment: Instead of deleting and recreating the question you should [edit] them, that way comments & history don't get lost. Note that frequent deleting of questions will sooner or later get you question banned.

Comment: @cafce25 Yes, from now on I will make sure to edit the content of the article instead of deleting it. I thought that the content needed to change greatly, but I realize now that my thinking was short-sighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two problems with your code for `line == "PB"` the first is that you're deleting all the data you collected in
`poly`, create a new one and then move that into `surface.polygons`, the other is the test on `== "PB"` would require a test if this is the first polygon.
So Rust just caught a bug for you!

Instead try this:

```rust
//...
} else if line == "PE" {
    surface.polygons.push(poly);
    poly = Polygon::new();
}
//...
```

Comment: Thank you. The method you told me is working well. By any chance, is there a way to handle it only in PB if there is no PE syntax?

Comment: I've confirmed that the question in the above comment works by using "surface.polygons.push(poly);" before "poly = Polygon::new();". I'll try applying it in this way.

Comment: Yes you just have to add a check if you're at the first time `PB` encountered and not do the push in that case.